# Windows 10 keeps waking up at night, source unknown, what to do?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, sleep, energy-saving, powercfg

I have recently upgraded a Win7 Pro machine to Win10, and since that day, every few days, the computer wakes up at nicht, once at 3:30 in the morning, the other time at 2:30 in the morning.

I already disabled waking for all devices, including mouses, keyboards, network adapters, etc.

The worst thing is that Windows does not say what actually caused the waking up, I think maybe the Windows update is the culrpit, but shouldn't Windows update make a corresponding entry?

These are my powercfg outputs, what else can I try to find out what keeps waking my computer up?

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
KEIN (none)

powercfg -lastwake
Aktivierungsverlaufsanzahl - 1
Aktivierungsverlauf [0]
Aktivierungsquellenanzahl  - 0
```

Comment: Go to Settings, System, Power & sleep, click Additional power settings, at power option windows click Change plan settings from your prefered plans, click Change advanced power settings, navigate to Sleep section and click (+) at the Sleep section, click (+) at Allow wake timers and disable the setting.

Comment: If you suspect the wake up caused by internet activity, open device manager, right click your network adapter that you used (eg: Gigabit Network Adapter for LAN) click properties, click Power management tab and untick Allow this device to wake the computer.

Answer (score 2):

3:30 in the morning sounds exactly like Windows Update's default schedule. It wakes the PC to install updates.

You can adjust the time under **Settings** -> **Updates and Restore** -> **Advanced Settings** (actual names might differ, I'm not at my PC and using German locale).

Comment: Hmm, all I can select here is "automatic (recommended)" and "ask before restart", and I have selected the second option. But where exactly can I prevent Windows from planning the restart at night?

Answer (score 1):

> In Windows 10, the new action center is where you'll find app
>   notifications and quick actions. But the old action center is still
>   here—it's been renamed Security and Maintenance. And it's still where
>   you go to change your security settings.
>
> In the search box, enter **security and maintenance** and then select
>   **Security and Maintenance**.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/change-security-and-maintenance-settings-in-windows-10

Within the **Security and Maintenance** windows you should be able to see a link labelled **Change maintenance settings** that will take you to a familiar screen where you can change the time Windows 10 performs automatic maintenance (install updates etc.).